# Finding original width and height of AABB

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a rotated rectangle that I don't know the original width and height of. As the current width and height is just the bounding box encapsulating the rectangle, how would I find the actual width and height? I currently have the rotation, bounds of the bounding box, and the center point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the current bounding box is $A$ wide by $B$ high and the original rectangle is $a$ wide by $b$ high, and the rotation angle is $\theta$, we have $B=b |\cos \theta| +a |\sin \theta|, A=a |\cos \theta|+b |\sin \theta|$.  These are two equations in two unknowns.  For simplicity, let $c=|\cos \theta|, s=|\sin \theta|$  Then the equations become $A=ac+bs, B=bc+as$  We can use substitution to get $$A=ac+bs \\ B=bc+as \\a=\frac 1c(A-bs)\\B=bc+\frac sc(A-bs) \\b=\frac{B-\frac scA}{c-\frac{s^2}c}\\a=\frac{A-\frac scB}{c-\frac{s^2}c}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, although it doesn't seem to work for me. I created a test example where I do know the before and after widths and heights and this formula doesn't equate to the known dimensions.

Comment: @CalenderMan:  Found a couple errors.  Give it a try.

Comment: Hmm, it gets within 1 when using 60 or 30 degrees but using something like 20 or 15 then it ends up being way out. Really appreciate the help, but I think I'll just try to find a way to not need the width and height. Thanks.

Comment: @CalenderMan:  I tried it with $a=13, b=5, s=\frac 5{13}$ and it was exact.  Could you give the values that are a problem?

Comment: Why is s = 5/13? I was just using s = sin of the angle.

Comment: @CalenderMan:  yes it is.  That is how I chose the angle to use, because it was convenient.  It doesn't have to be the same as $\frac ab$

Comment: ah ok, as for what I was using, the original height = 60, original width = 87, angle was 20. That should give 87.4 height and 103.6 width.

Comment: @CalenderMan:  from those values I get $A=102.2745, B=86.1373$ and they invert to within $10^{-4}$

Comment: Ah yeah, it is right, I was calculating it wrongly somehow. Thanks, this will help me so much.